# Setting up distibution for Android App in certain countries

Tags: android

I want my free app to be for download in only a select few countries. ie  to implement "Not for download in your country" based on the country the user belongs to. 
Does the "Distribute in these countries" option in my Play Store Developer console do the same?

PS: Also I'd like it if the app is still searchable on PS in different countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to chose countries in developers console. But then this app it is not searchable on PS in deselected countries.

Only when someone from deselected country click in link to your app in PS directly will see information "Not for download in your country".

Have fun.

Comment: Dude thanks man! I'll add it as the answer as soon as 10 mins passby. Also I cant change the com.myapp.something markup link right. I'll have to add a new app with the changed link and same name?

Comment: Nope, you cannot change it after publish. Like @LuckyMe sad :
You only can upload a new package as a new app. You can look at the Google's app *Talk*, it's name was change to *Hangout*, but package name is still *com.google.android.talk*.

Comment: But if you **don't publish** your app yet, this link will be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: Thanks man, had I learnt it last night it would have been better. Published Already :) Thanks again tho.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can un-check all the countries in which you don't want your app to be available.

users who belongs to restricted countries won't be able to search your app in play store though